# Android detecting incoming and outgoing calls is not working with Redmi and Oppo mobiles

Tags: java, android

Here is my code:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            showToast(context,"Call started...");
        }
        else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            showToast(context,"Call ended...");
        }
        else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            showToast(context,"Incoming call...");
        }
    }

    void showToast(Context context,String message){
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

//here i have registered my receiver in manifest

```
  <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I am detecting incoming and outgoing calls in my Android application. This code is not working with the device Redmi and Oppo, and I want the code to be working for all the devices. How can I determine what the issue is?

Comment: Hi @Vishali have you managed to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits, apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest. you can register your receiver dynamically in Activity by calling `registerReceiver(new CallReceiver(), new IntentFilter().addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));`
also, a bad thing about this approach is your receiver will only work when your app is in the foreground. If you close your app then you don't trigger any broadcasts in background. also, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716904/android-o-phone-state-broadcast-limitation) if you are looking for call log data.

Comment: please suggest me the solution when app is in both foreground and background

Comment: I prefer using JobScheduler instead of broadcast receiver. this will work even if your app is in background